# Javascript Array inside an array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript. I tried to achieve this output in array but I really cannot do it.

Output should be:

```
["test", "test1"],
["test2", "test3"]
```

From this:

The data from items:

```
items = [
    {
       data1: "test",
       data2: "test1"
    },
    {
       data1: "test2",
       data2: "test3"
    },
]
```

I tried to push to a new array in here but not working. Is there any workaround here?

```
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i]
  }
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't do anything. Can you post what you have actualy tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method

```js
var items = [{
  data1: "test",
  data2: "test1"
}, {
  data1: "test2",
  data2: "test3"
}, ];

console.log(
  items.map(function(obj) {
    return [obj.data1, obj.data2]
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `Array.prototype.reduce` and listing out all the values from `items` into an array and not just `data1` and `data2`:

```js
var items=[{data1:"test",data2:"test1"},{data1:"test2",data2:"test3"}];

var result = items.reduce(function(prev,curr){
  prev.push(Object.keys(curr).map(e=>curr[e]));
  return prev;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for you :

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6jgmomd/)

```
var items= [
   {
     data1: "test",
     data2: "test1"
   },
   {
     data1: "test2",
     data2: "test3"
   },
];
for(i in items){
   array=[];
   for(j in items[i]){
      array.push(items[i][j])
   }
   console.log(array);
}
```